# Pass data from one controller to another via segue and Navigation on different storyboard, Swift, iOS, Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to pass some data via segue from one storyboard to another, the second storyboard VC is embedded in a navigation controller, I cannot find a place to add the nav controller in code, When I do I get an error saying the segue link doesn't exist.

here is my code:-

prepare for.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ProdProj", bundle: nil) 
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProjectsListVC") as? ProjectsListVC

            vc!.projectsSentT = ProjecctProd
            vc!.logedInAsT = "Prod"
```

and my perform.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProjectsProd", sender: nil)
```

if I add navigation to perform segue I get an error saying there is no segue with that name.
If I don't add navigation it says there is no view controller with the name ProjectsListVC

screenshots.
[The link and name of segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n94R.png)

[image: Name of the VC going to]

Comment: of course you cannot perform a segue like action on two different storyboard first case is that.
 for second case please attach screenshot of sotyabord  that shows storyboard name ViewController + its identifier it will help to answer you correctly

Comment: Thank you for your comment I have added the screen shot of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must take into account the navigation controller in the next storyboard, so your prepare(for: sender:) function should look like this:

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DestinationViewController
    vc!.projectsSentT = ProjecctProd
    vc!.logedInAsT = "Prod"
   }
```

where DestinationViewController is the name of the second view controller embedded in the navigationController. And use segue.destination not and instance of the viewController directly.

Comment: Thank you for your time on this, This worked for me and Thank you for the explanation, I did understand I needed to ref that it was going to a Nav controller but for the life of me couldn't find help on it that made sense. All the best

Comment: your Wellcome man, is very unclear when noter worked like this, but once you see it once is clear that all object in storyboard mustbe referenced to segue.

Answer (score 0):

First, create Storyboard Reference on first storyboard, like this:
[image: Attributes inspector]

Next, create segue to the reference:
[image: segue]

For send data to new controller use prepare method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare